# Unit Testing MVP using mockito with event listeners

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

```
Android Studio 2.1.2
```

I want to test that the callbacks onUsernameError, onPasswordError, and onSuccess, in the LoginModelImp are actually called. I am not sure how to test event listeners. However, the test fails as those functions are never called. I am mocking them with mockito and trying to verify them.

This is my code so far.

Presenter interface

```
public interface LoginPresenterContract<LoginFragmentViewContract> {
    void validateCredentials();

    void attachView(LoginFragmentViewContract view);
    void detachView();
}
```

Presenter implementation

```
public class LoginPresenterImp implements LoginPresenterContract<LoginFragmentViewContract>, LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener {

    private LoginModelContract mLoginModelContract;
    private LoginFragmentViewContract mLoginFragmentView;

    public LoginPresenterImp(LoginModelContract loginModelContract) {
        mLoginModelContract = loginModelContract;
    }

    /*
     * LoginPresenterContact - implementation
     */
    @Override
    public void attachView(LoginFragmentViewContract view) {
        mLoginFragmentView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        mLoginFragmentView = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void validateCredentials() {
        if(mLoginModelContract != null) {
            mLoginModelContract.login(
                    mLoginFragmentView.getUsername(),
                    mLoginFragmentView.getPassword(),
                    LoginPresenterImp.this);
        }
    }

    /*
     * LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener - implementation
     */
    @Override
    public void onUsernameError() {
        if(mLoginFragmentView != null) {
            mLoginFragmentView.onLoginFailed("Incorrect username");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordError() {
        if(mLoginFragmentView != null) {
            mLoginFragmentView.onLoginFailed("Incorrect password");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if(mLoginFragmentView != null) {
            mLoginFragmentView.onLoginSuccess();
        }
    }
}
```

Model interface

```
public interface LoginModelContract {
    interface OnLoginCompletedListener {
        void onUsernameError();
        void onPasswordError();
        void onSuccess();
    }
    void login(String username, String password, OnLoginCompletedListener onLoginCompletedListener);
}
```

Model Implementation

```
public class LoginModelImp implements LoginModelContract {
    /* Testing Valid username and passwords */
    private static String validUsername = "steve";
    private static String validPassword = "1234";

    @Override
    public void login(final String username,
                      final String password,
                      final OnLoginCompletedListener onLoginCompletedListener) {

        boolean hasSuccess = true;
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username) || !username.equals(validUsername)) {
        /* TEST onUsernameError() */
            onLoginCompletedListener.onUsernameError();
            hasSuccess = false;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || !password.equals(validPassword)) {
        /* TEST onPasswordError() */
            onLoginCompletedListener.onPasswordError();
            hasSuccess = false;
        }

        if(hasSuccess) {
        /* TEST onSuccess() */
            onLoginCompletedListener.onSuccess();
        }
    }
}
```

JUnit4 test with Mockito

```
public class LoginPresenterImpTest {
    private LoginFragmentViewContract mMockViewContract;
    private LoginModelContract mMockModelContract;
    private LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener mMockOnLoginCompletedListener;
    private LoginPresenterContract<LoginFragmentViewContract> mLoginPresenterContract;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mMockViewContract = Mockito.mock(LoginFragmentViewContract.class);
        mMockModelContract = Mockito.mock(LoginModelContract.class);
        mMockOnLoginCompletedListener = Mockito.mock(LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener.class);
        mLoginPresenterContract = new LoginPresenterImp(mMockModelContract);
        mLoginPresenterContract.attachView(mMockViewContract);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessWithValidCredentials() {
        when(mMockViewContract.getUsername()).thenReturn("steve");
        when(mMockViewContract.getPassword()).thenReturn("1234");

        mLoginPresenterContract.validateCredentials();

        verify(mMockViewContract, times(1)).getUsername();
        verify(mMockViewContract, times(1)).getPassword();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onSuccess();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onPasswordError();
        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onUsernameError();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to test this implementation?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test class `LoginPresenterImpTest` is about the test of `LoginPresenterImp` class, and it should use only its actual implementation and the mocks of its collaborators. The class `LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener` is a collaborator of `LoginModelImp`, so in a well designed, and pure unit-test of `LoginPresenterImp`, like yours, it's perfectly normal that it is never called.
The solution I propose is to test the LoginModelImp separately:

```
public class LoginModelImpTest {

    private LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener mMockOnLoginCompletedListener;
    private LoginModelImp loginModelImp;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mMockOnLoginCompletedListener = Mockito.mock(LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener.class);
        loginModelImp = new LoginModelImp();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessWithValidCredentials() {

        loginModelImp.login("steve", "1234", mMockOnLoginCompletedListener);;

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onSuccess();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onPasswordError();
        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onUsernameError();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you have to use the actual implementation of `LoginModelImp` in your `LoginPresenterImpTest` and spy on your listener (that is the presenter itself) or to configure the mocks to make them call the listener. Here's an example, but I wouldn't use this one:

```
public class LoginPresenterImpTest {
    private LoginFragmentViewContract mMockViewContract;
    private LoginModelContract mModelContract;
    private LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener mMockOnLoginCompletedListener;
    private LoginPresenterContract<LoginFragmentViewContract> mLoginPresenterContract;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mMockViewContract = Mockito.mock(LoginFragmentViewContract.class);
        mModelContract = new LoginModelImp();
        LoginPresenterImp spyPresenterImp = Mockito.spy(new LoginPresenterImp(mModelContract));
        mLoginPresenterContract = spyPresenterImp;
        mMockOnLoginCompletedListener = spyPresenterImp;
        mLoginPresenterContract.attachView(mMockViewContract);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessWithValidCredentials() {
        when(mMockViewContract.getUsername()).thenReturn("steve");
        when(mMockViewContract.getPassword()).thenReturn("1234");

        mLoginPresenterContract.validateCredentials();

        verify(mMockViewContract, times(1)).getUsername();
        verify(mMockViewContract, times(1)).getPassword();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onSuccess();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onPasswordError();
        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onUsernameError();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, This seems like a good solution. Just waiting to seen other responses.

Comment: Hey @Lorenzo i'm facing same problem but in my case i want to validate against sqlite data base any idea how to do that?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to the difference between User Story and Use Case.   In this case, you have 1 User Story  (e.g. "As a User, I want to Login, so I provide my Username and Password"),  but there are actually at least 3 Use Cases:  Right Username/Right Password,  Right Username/Wrong Password,  Wrong Username/Right Password, etc.   As a general best practice, you want for Tests to correspond 1:1 with Use Cases,  so I would recommend something like this:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldCompleteWithValidCredentials() {
    mMockModelContract.login("steve", "1234", 
                              mMockOnLoginCompletedListener);

    verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onSuccess();     
 }

 @Test
 public void shouldNotCompleteWithInvalidUser() {
    mMockModelContract.login("wrong_user", "1234",
                               mMockOnLoginCompletedListener);
    verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, 
                            times(1)).onUsernameError();      
 }

@Test
public void shouldNotCompleteWithInvalidPassword() {
    mMockModelContract.login("steve", "wrong_password", 
                         mMockOnLoginCompletedListener);
    verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onPasswordError();
}
```

In other words,  for Test 1, you are trying to positively verify that, when the Username and Password complete,  Success is invoked.   For Test 2,  you are verifying the conditions to call onUsernameError and for 3, the ones for onPasswordError.   All three are valid things to test,  and you are right to want to verify they are called,  but you need to treat them as different Use Cases.

For completeness,  I would verify what happens on Wrong_User/Wrong_Password,  and also verify what happens if there is a Wrong_Password condition N times  (do you need blocking of the Account?).

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are mocking the `LoginModelContract` and `OnLoginCompletedListener` you can not assert that `onUsernameError`, `onPasswordError`, and `onSuccess` are actually called because by mocking `LoginModelContract` the "real" login method (which should call these methods) would not get executed but only the mocked method would be called.
You could trigger these methods with something like:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        OnLoginCompletedListener listener = (OnLoginCompletedListener) args[2];
        listener.onUsernameError();
        return null;
    }
}).when(mMockModelContract).login(anyString(), anyString(), any(OnLoginCompletedListener.class)).thenAnswer();
```

But of cause such a test would make not sense because you are explicitly calling what you are trying to test.

In my opinion it would make more sense to just test the `LoginModelContract` without the `LoginFragmentViewContract` and `LoginPresenterContract`.
Something like:

```
public class LoginPresenterImpTest {
    private LoginModelContract mMockModelContract;
    private LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener mMockOnLoginCompletedListener;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mMockOnLoginCompletedListener = Mockito.mock(LoginModelContract.OnLoginCompletedListener.class);
        mMockModelContract = new LoginModelContract();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSuccessWithValidCredentials() {
        mMockModelContract.login("steve", "1234", mMockOnLoginCompletedListener);

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, times(1)).onSuccess();

        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onPasswordError();
        verify(mMockOnLoginCompletedListener, never()).onUsernameError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing your point, but have you tried using PowerMock?

You'll need the following dependencies:

- testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5"
- testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.5"
- testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5"
- testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.5"

And then use it this way:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(DownloadPresenterContract.Events.class)
public class DownloadModelTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private DownloadPresenterContract.Events mockEvents;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         this.mockEvents = PowerMockito.spy(new DownloadPresenterContract.Events());

         PowerMockito.whenNew(DownloadPresenterContract.Events.class)
                     .withNoArguments()
                     .thenReturn(this.mockEvents); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticMocking() {

         //Do your logic, which should trigger mockEvents actions

         Mockito.verify(this.mockEvents, Mockito.times(1)).onDownloadSuccess();
         //Or use this:
         //PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(this.mockEvents, times(1)).invoke("onDownloadSuccess", "someParam");
}
```

}

Comment: I had a problem with PowerMockito.spy(new DownloadPresenterContract.Events()) As you can't create a new instance of a interface. However, I have changed the code in my question to something easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to create an instance using PowerMockito.spy(new DownloadPresenterContract.Events()). You can do this way: PowerMockito.whenNew(DownloadPresenterContract.Events.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(Mockito.mock(DownloadPresenterContract.Events.class)). In other words you tell it "no matter who will be creating a new instance of this, give him a mocked response".

Comment: In any case there are two options: 1) you're applying classloader magic (like PowerMock) making AST proxies around classes; 2) you're applying OOP magic mocking everyone till you get what you need. I prefer the first variant because it's shorter. Even if you're dealing with an interface, there should be someone concrete who is calling a constructor reference.

Comment: One more option. You can apply Visitor/Observer pattern to LoginPresenterImp. Thus, LoginPresenterImp should take a Function instance which will be called on interactions (for instance within attachView method). Main implementation can be using it for validation, though test implementation would be wrapping them with Mockito::spy.